C++ library for part-of-speech tagging in English
I am looking for a C++ library that:

does part-of-speech tagging in English.
has a license allowing commercial use and doesn't force the program to be open source.
is still maintained or has been updated sometimes in the last 5 years.
is in C/C++ and has no Python binding, unlike spacy-cpp.
smaller than 100 MB (i.e., no onnx of some LLM unless it's < 100 MB)


I'm curious, why is the Python binding a problem?

MIT licensed POS tagger for English that uses mlpack (C++, BSD-licensed lib): https://github.com/kiner-shah/mlpack_examples/tree/main/example_hidden_markov_model

If anyone faces difficulty understanding the code, they can refer the videos: Part 1 and Part 2.
